menhir `--interpret` for multiple files
I'm trying to use --interpret flag in Menhir to debug my parser, and I have separated my .mly files into tokens and grammar like this:
.
├── dune
├── lexer.mll
├── parser.mly
├── syntax.ml
└── tokens.mly

When using this command:
menhir ./tokens.mly --base ./parser.mly

I got this: Error: no start symbol has been declared.
However, the start symbol is defined in my parser.mly as %start <item> item.
If I then add a --only-tokens flag for tokens.mly like menhir --only-tokens ./tokens.mly --base ./parser.mly, the error will not show up but Menhir will quit immediately.
How should I use Menhir interpret properly for multiple files then?

After seeing this post, I was able to solve the problem:
menhir tokens.mly --only-tokens
menhir parser.mly tokens.mly --external-tokens Tokens --base parser --interpret

